# NCLOB data Table from Oracle to MySQL Data Migration 5.7.38

Tags: mysql, oracle, nclob

I am migrating from Oracle to MySQL on AWS RDS.
MySQL version is 5.7.38.
One of the DB table has data in NCLOB format.
While migrating to MySQL the XML data is trimmed in Long Text format.
I used AWS DMS tool.

Can you recommend how to migrate the specific table having NCLOB from Oracle to MySQL differently?